# replace one single quote with two single quotes only if the line doesn't start with #

Tags: regex, ant

I tried to create a regex replace (using ant) to do some replacement.

The text file which should be worked on contains lines some of which start with `#` some don't. I want to do the replacement of the `'` only in the lines which do NOT start with `#`

For this I already found out that `^(?!#)` will delete those lines from the result.

Also I already have the following old replacement regex which replaces ALL the occurrences of `'` with `''`:

```
match="([^'])'([^'])"
    replace="\1''\2"
    flags="g">
    <fileset dir="src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/">
        <include name="myfiles*.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

I am just too stupid to bring those both bits together. I used https://regexr.com/ to interactively test the new regex replacment.

Any tips highly appreciated.

Example Text to parse:

```
# this is a comment with ' which should not be replaced
Bc700000456=translation text which may also include ' which actually be replace
```

Best regards
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

Marrying your two requirements is quite tricky in JavaScript. But fortunately it *is* possible!

```
((?:^(?:#.*\n)*(?!#)[^'\n]*)?)'([^'\n]*(?:\n(?:#.*\n)*(?!#)[^'\n]*)?(?=')|[\s\S]*)
```

See it in action at: http://regexr.com/3h3uk

Caveat: this fails in the special case that your input does not contain any `'` characters outside of comments.

The regex is a little complicated, but the basic methodology is this: match up to the next `'` by eating through all comments. After that, match up to the next `'` by either eating through all comments until the next uncommented `'`, or eat until the end of the string. Thus the expression relies on at least one occurrence of `'` to work properly, otherwise certain commented `'`s will be replaced. This is unavoidable given JavaScript regex's limited functionality. But you can program this logic into your code if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use ant but since it can use the java.util.regex package (You can choose which is the default package for regex with [the property ant.regexp.regexpimpl](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/regexp.html)), I assume that the `\G` anchor is supported (in the worst case it can be done without it) as well as possessive quantifiers.

You can use this pattern:

```
\G([^#']*+(?:(?m:^#.*|#)[^#']*|''+[^#']*)*+)'
```

with `\1''` as replacement.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LE5iy/1)

The idea is to force all matches to be contiguous with the `\G` anchor and to capture all that doesn't need to be replaced before a single quote (i.e. lines starting with `#`,  consecutive single quotes, and obviously all that isn't a single quote).

---

Without these features you can also do it with:

```
([^#']*(?:(?:^#.*|#)[^#']*|''+[^#']*)*)('|(?![\s\S]))
```

and this replacement: `\1\2\2`

But you need to add the m flag.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LE5iy/2)

Here the contiguity is ensured by the ability of the pattern to match each position in the string from the start to the end.

Comment: for me it worked with \1 (using it in under windows / eclipse )

Comment: I see already -2 for this answer and don't understand why people are downvoting your answer`?

Comment: Furthermore: you write for your second version "... you need to add the m flag". So are we looking at "gm" flag or only "m" flag?

Comment: @user668338: Thanks for the precision, I will edit the answer with the good replacement. About the downvotes, I assume people doesn't have anything else to do (in particular writing a good answer). About the flags, you have to add the m flag, so the flag attribute must be `gm`.

Comment: Are you sure with \1\2\2 in the second version? How would you add a ' with that?

Comment: @user668338: Yes I'm sure. Because the group 2 captures the single quote or an empty string at the end of the string. `\2\2` puts two single quotes or nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Hannes,

Solving your problem would be easier if i could have some text your are trying to parse.

Cal

in the meanwhile i have this regex here that will work if both ends have a '. 
https://regex101.com/r/ylnpCw/2 , this may work better for you then.

Comment: I am not sure but the replacement should only be done if the line does NOT start with #